# I need a function that after three posts give me my add then after four posts give my add fifth then

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need a function that after three posts give me my add then after four posts give my add fifth then after eight posts give new my add then a big banner in the middle then again the same scene the same series starts.  Go to the loop and then down to the pagination ETC...

Post1   Post2    Image
Post4    Post5    Post6
Image    Post8    Post9
Post10   Post11   Post12
Post13   Post14   Image
Big Image
Post16   Post17   Image
Post19   Post20   Post21 
Image    Post23   Post24

Pagination 1 2 3 4 5 ....

Like this Help Me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfeBY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add code to the loop in your theme.  If this is your home page, then you would edit the loop in index.php.  If it's a category page or you want it to apply to those pages too, you'll edit the loop in archive.php (assuming you don't have a template file targeting categories, in which case you'd edit it there as well).

The start of the loop will look something like (or exactly) like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Before this line, add an array containing the HTML for your ads, like this:

```
<?php 
  $ads = [
    '<div class="post-ad"><a href="enter-url-here"><img src="ad-image-here" /></a></div>',
    '<div class="post-ad"><a href="enter-url-here"><img src="ad-image-here" /></a></div>',
    '<div class="post-ad"><a href="enter-url-here"><img src="ad-image-here" /></a></div>',
    // and so on
  ];
?>
```

Also before the loop starts, add a counter variable and an array of the positions you want the ads to show in:

```
<?php 
  $count = 0; 
  $ad_positions = [3, 7, 11, 15]; // enter the desired positions
?>
```

Inside the loop, add this code that increments the counter variable, and outputs ads based on the counter variable:

```
<?php
  $count++;
  if( in_array( $count, $ad_positions ) ){
    $ad = array_shift( $ads ); // gets and removes the first ad from the array
    echo $ad;
    
  } 
?>
```

So your while loop will be this (now that I have that code to look at:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
  the_post();
                
  $count++;
  if( in_array( $count, $ad_positions ) ){
    $ad = array_shift( $ads ); // gets and removes the first ad from the array
    echo $ad;
    $count++;  // the ad takes up a position, so this will make the next one appear in the right place.
  }
  get_template_part( $template ); 
endwhile;
```

Comment: Parse error :  syntax error, unexpected token ";" in  C:\xampp\htdocs\car\wp-content\themes\motors\listings\filter\results.php

Comment: I've updated my answer with the complete while loop.  Replace your while loop with this one.

Comment: array not Display Same positions

Comment: Are they one position off?

Comment: All positions off  See link https://www.splitarts.net/smr/search-cars/

 $count = 0; 
  $ad_positions = [3, 6, 13, 16, 21]; // enter the desired positions

Comment: I think I understand - this is just a miscommunication.  I've updated the code for the loop, adding an increment to the $count variable whenever an ad is output.  This should make the following ads show in the positions you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];
$ads = [
    '<div class="post-ad"><a href="enter-url-here"><img src="ad-image-here" /></a></div>',
    '<div class="post-ad"><a href="enter-url-here"><img src="ad-image-here" /></a></div>',
    '<div class="post-ad"><a href="enter-url-here"><img src="ad-image-here" /></a></div>',
    // and so on
  ];
  $count = 0; 
  $ad_positions = [3, 7, 11, 15]; // enter the desired positions
if ( have_posts() ) :
    $nuxy_mod_option = apply_filters( 'stm_me_get_nuxy_mod', 'list', 'listing_view_type' );
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $nuxy_mod_option = apply_filters( 'stm_me_get_nuxy_mod', 'grid', 'listing_view_type_mobile' );
    }
    if ( function_exists( 'stm_is_multilisting' ) && stm_is_multilisting() && wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $mltSlug         = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
        $nuxy_mod_option = apply_filters( 'stm_me_get_nuxy_mod', 'grid', $mltSlug . '_view_type_mobile' );
    }
    $view_type = apply_filters( 'stm_listings_input', $nuxy_mod_option, 'view_type' );
    /*Filter Badges*/
    do_action( 'stm_listings_load_template', 'filter/badges' );
    if ( boolval( apply_filters( 'is_listing', array() ) ) && 'sold_car' !== $type ) {
        do_action( 'stm_listings_load_template', 'classified/filter/featured' );
    }
    ?>
    <div class="stm-isotope-sorting stm-isotope-sorting-<?php echo esc_attr( $view_type ); ?>">
        <?php
        if ( 'grid' === $view_type ) :
            ?>
        <div class="row row-3 car-listing-row car-listing-modern-grid">
            <?php
        endif;
            $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-' . $view_type . '-loop';
        if ( apply_filters( 'stm_is_ev_dealer', false ) || boolval( apply_filters( 'is_listing', array( 'listing', 'listing_two', 'listing_two_elementor', 'listing_three', 'listing_three_elementor', 'listing_one_elementor' ) ) ) || apply_filters( 'stm_is_dealer_two', false ) || apply_filters( 'stm_is_listing_five', false ) || apply_filters( 'stm_is_listing_six', false ) ) {
            $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-' . $view_type . '-directory-loop';
        } elseif ( apply_filters( 'stm_is_listing_four', false ) ) {
            $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-four-' . $view_type . '-loop';
        } elseif ( apply_filters( 'stm_is_boats', false ) && 'list' === $view_type ) {
            $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-' . $view_type . '-loop-boats';
        } elseif ( apply_filters( 'stm_is_motorcycle', false ) ) {
            $template = 'partials/listing-cars/motos/' . $view_type;
        } elseif ( apply_filters( 'stm_is_aircrafts', false ) ) {
            $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-aircrafts-' . $view_type;
        }
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            get_template_part( $template );     
            $count++;
            if( in_array( $count, $ad_positions ){
                $ad = array_shift( $ads ); // gets and removes the first ad from the array
                echo $ad;
            } )
            endwhile;
        if ( 'grid' === $view_type ) :
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    if ( is_null( $navigation_type ) || 'pagination' === $navigation_type ) :
stm_listings_load_pagination();
    else :
        $ppp   = $query->query['posts_per_page'];
        $paged = ( ! empty( $query->query['paged'] ) && 1 !== $query->query['paged'] ) ? $query->query['paged'] + 1 : 2;
        if ( $ppp < $query->found_posts ) {
            echo "<a class='btn stm-inventory-load-more-btn' href='#' data-ppp='" . esc_attr( $ppp ) . "' data-page='" . esc_attr( $paged ) . "' data-nav='load_more' data-offset='1'>" . esc_html__( 'Load More', 'motors' ) . '</a>';
        }
    endif;
    wp_reset_query(); //phpcs:ignore
    ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no results', 'motors' ); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'stm_is_aircrafts', false ) ) : ?>
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
            var showing = '<?php echo esc_html( $query->found_posts ); ?>';
            jQuery('.ac-total').text('<?php echo esc_html( $query->found_posts ); ?>');
            if(showing === '0') {
jQuery('.ac-showing').text('0');
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: see image]

post1 | Post 2 | Custom Ads

Custom Ads | post 3 | post4

display Ads Same positions In Wordpress Website

Array is not displaying properly due to which the layout of the design is too much out

'

```
<?php $count = 0; 
$ad_positions = [3,4]; // enter the desired positions
$ads = [
    '<div class="dp-in swiper-slide">
        <div class="listing-car-item">
            <div class="listing-car-item-inner">
                <img decoding="async" class="img-responsive s" src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/deal.png">
                <h3>looking for a deal?</h3>
                <p>save big on discounted cars.</p>
                <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-sm" href="#"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">SHOP DEALS</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>',
    '<div class="dp-in swiper-slide">
        <div class="listing-car-item">
            <div class="listing-car-item-inner">
            <img decoding="async" class="img-responsive s" src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/trade.png">
            <h3>looking for a deal?</h3>
            <p>save big on discounted cars.</p>
            <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-sm" href="#"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">SHOP DEALS</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>',
    // and so on
  ];

while ( $special_query->have_posts() ) :
                    
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { 
                        $count++;
                        if( in_array( $count, $ad_positions ) ){
                          $ad = array_shift( $ads ); // gets and removes the first ad from the array
                          echo $ad ; 
                        }
                    }
                 ?>
'
```